# Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed. To connect excel 2016

Tags: c#, oledb, adodb

I am trying to read from Excel 2016 file using

`strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strXLPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\";";.`

I am using ActivexObject and ADODB.Connection to open the connection to excel file. I am getting

> Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed

error. I am using c# in .Net 3.5, Access Database Engine 2010 (64 bit) and Office 2016(64 Bit) and windows 7(64 bit) and Visual Studio 2008. Please help me. I've searched so much but couldn't find any solution for this. I'm attaching my code and the error image.[ADODB error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52Pe7.png).

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
    function IsXLValid() {


        var strXLPath = document.getElementById('<% =FileUpload.ClientID%>').value

        var len = strXLPath.length;

        if (len == 0) {
            alert("Please select batch control numbers spreadsheet to upload.");
            return false;
        }

        //var regex = "^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\\\{2}\\w+)\\$?)(\\\\(\\w[\\w].*))(.(X|x)(L|l)(S|s))$";
        var regex = "^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\\\{2}\\w+)\\$?)(\\\\(\\w[\\w].*))(.(X|x)(L|l)(S|s)(M|m))$";

        if (!(strXLPath.match(regex))) {
            alert(strXLPath + " is not a valid excel file.");
            return false;
        }

        //var strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + strXLPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=YES\"";
        var strConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + strXLPath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\";";

        var conn = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection");


        conn.open(strConnString, "", "");

        var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

        var rsrowCount = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

        var schemaRS = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");

        var adSchemaTables = 20;

        schemaRS = conn.OpenSchema(adSchemaTables);

        strdatatype = schemaRS.fields(2).value;

        var datatype = "ERISAREQ$";

        if (strdatatype !== datatype) {

            alert(strXLPath + " is not a valid spreadsheet with the numbers: " + strdatatype + "");
            rs = null;
            rsSheet = null;
            conn.close();
            conn = null;
            return false

        }

       rs = conn.execute("select * from ZRangeValid");
        if (rs.fields(0).value != 'YES') {
            alert(strXLPath + " requested numbers spreadsheet is not valid.\nPlease validate the spreadsheet data and retry.")
            rs = null;
            rsSheet = null;
            conn.close();
            conn = null;
            return false

        }

         rsrowCount = conn.execute("SELECT COUNT([Control Number]) from [ERISAREQ$]");

        if (rsrowCount.fields(0).value < 70) 
        {
            var answer = confirm("Uploaded Spreadsheet has less than 70 Numbers, would you like to proceed..?")
            if (answer) 
            {

                rsrowCount = null;
                rsSheet = null;
                conn.close();
                conn = null;
                return true;

            }
            else 
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true
        rs = null;
        rsSheet = null;
        conn.close();
        conn = null;

    }

    function trim(str) {
        return str.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved, when I installed Access Database Engine 2010(32-bit), I was using 64-bit engine, where my ASP.net application is running in 32-bit mode as Visual Studio has 32 bit web server(WebDev.WebServer.exe).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual studio, you can use server explorer, connect to access db file with selecting oledb provider, and then in property window you can get connection string.

Comment: thank you for reply, but can you be more clear about server explorer. I'm not aware of it. I want to read from excel 2016 file within the given javascript function.

Comment: ok, but here my data source is an excel file, there it's .accdb file, how can I use .xlsx file as .accdb file?

Comment: Oh, i am so sorry, Excel file is not Database file, First of all you convert the file to access db file. 
In access environment you can import data from excel files and make database file from the datas. Each sheet in excel file can be convert to a table.
In Access in External Data tab click excel button.

Comment: But if you want work on excel files, you cannot use sql commands, you must work on sheets, rows and columns. I suggest to use libraries like sheetJS or JSpreadsheets. You can search to find other alternative tools.

Comment: But can you tell me why am I getting that error. It was working fine with Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0(with .xls files). When I want to use it for .xlsx, this error is coming. Any idea?

Comment: Try to change your ie version to the version 9. I'm using ie 9, windows 7 and excel 2007 and the code works for me without the problem.

Comment: Now this issue is solved as I explained in my Answer, but I'm getting some other issue which I asked as a separate question. This is the question >> [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034216/external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format-while-using-activexobjectadodb-con)